# irb `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, irb

I try to modify paperclip image from my model after a server change.

I have a file with id of my model and name of image like that

```
3;3da442247510f15c07fead8f41cd1c9441694b02.jpg
4;e3b652bfe16759002d6dd3da608475069df1c02e.jpg
5;0699ab4040c4d4f6e8ec390170014661bc5f6d96.jpg
```

I have write a script to find the file and give ti to my model

```
File.open("titi.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    tab=line.split(";")
    puts "id => #{tab[0]} | nom => #{tab[1]}"
    c=Contact.find(tab[0])
    file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/system/contact/#{tab[1]}")
    c.photo = file
    file.close
    c.save!
  end
end
```

I launch my script like that

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails runner script.rb
```

But I have this error

```
script.rb:6:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -  /var/www/contactmedia/public/system/contact/3da442247510f15c07fead8f41cd1c9441694b02.jpg (Errno::ENOENT)
```

but when I do

```
ls -la /var/www/contactmedia/public/system/contact/3da442247510f15c07fead8f41cd1c9441694b02.jpg
```

I have a file....

What is wrong in my script ? Whant can I test to move my images.

Thanks

EDIT

it's OK i have found why I read a windows file so i have a \r at end of line. I read my file like that now

```
file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/system/contact/#{tab[1].chom‌​p}")
```

Comment: What happens if you run `File.open("/var/www/contactmedia/public/system/contact/3da442247510f15c07fead8f41cd1c9441694b02.jpg")` in IRB?

Comment: #<File:/var/www/contactmedia/public/system/contact/3da442247510f15c07fead8f41cd1c9441694b02.jpg>